# android batch uninstall apps

Tags: android

1.I want to uninstall Multiple apps by once .
2.So is this,the code is what I try:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, Uri.parse(new StringBuilder(32).append("package:").append(packageName).toString()));
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

I make a cycle to execute this code. But only can uninstall one app ,the others not work.

Comment: "But no work". Can you be more specific?

Comment: only can uninstall one app, the others not work